# Web site and mobile app: how to combine this 2 IT support?

Tags: django, flutter

I've been working with Django for one year now, to develop web site applications.
And I've just started to learn about Flutter, the cross-plateform solution by Google to develop mobile app.

Having this 2 IT supports TOGETHER for the same project would be ideal.
That means web site application and mobile app should "share" the same database, at least for authentication (user should have the same account for web app and mobile app) but not only.

Basically, principle of my web site applications is to give a random number from a list. A number can only be assigned once. So, mobile app should share the same database to get access to the list of number to be assigned.

is it feasible?

Comment: Since we have no idea what your current application looks like, we cannot know how much work it would be, but two frontend applications sharing the same backend data is pretty common. It is possible, only you can find out if it's feasible with your current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please search for "RESTful API".
Maybe I don't understand all your mean. Client-server, Front-end back-end, Cross-platform concepts have been in use for a long time. Flutter(web or mobile) is often used for developing Front-end. Create a back-end which can be used for all of them

Comment: Thanks to both. I think API Rest could be a solution for bot using Django and Flutter but maybe Flutter could sufficient as it allow web and mobile app...